# Ejecutar aplicación con wine desde un terminal SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

He creado una maquina virtual ubuntu en Google Cloud, he instalado wine y accedo por consola ssh.

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una aplicación que es muy simple pero obtengo el siguiente error.

```
$ wine prefix32/RTHomeEngine1/RTSingleServer.exe
```

> 0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
>
> 0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
>
> wine: Unhandled exception 0x0eedfade in thread 9 at address 0x0000:0x7b43cb73 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
>
> 0009:err:seh:start_debugger Couldn't start debugger ("winedbg --auto 8 104") (2)
>   Read the Wine Developers Guide on how to set up winedbg or another debugger

Alguien que me pueda ayudar a entender el error o sepa posibles soluciones para intentarlas, por favor.

Comment: Cuanto te conectes vía ssh usa: ssh -X usuario@ip   Cuando te hayas conectado coloca  export DISPLAY=IP_DESDE_DONDETECONECTASTE luego invoca wine. ¿te sale el mismo error haciendo esto que te comento?

Comment: ¿que herramienta usas para conectarte por ssh? ¿moba, putty,  o lo haces desde la consola de otro linux?

Comment: Uso putty y la consola de Google Cloud también es SSH, voy a probar lo que mencionas y te comento.

Answer (score 0):

El error que te aparece es porque la aplicación que tratas de ejecutar necesita de una interfaz gráfica. Debido a que te conectas por SSH la aplicación no se puede ejecutar.

Sigue la guía en (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine) para que te conectes mediante "Remote Desktop" y puedas ejecutar la aplicación.